Checking whether Ricardian equivalence holds
If I need to check whether Ricardian equivalence holds in a given economy, I only need to look at whether the equality $G + \frac{G}{1 + r} = Nt + \frac{Nt}{1 + r}$ holds, right? (I'm using $G$ to mean government expenditure, $N$ the number of agents in the economy, $t$ the lump-sum tax each agent pays, and $r$ the interest rate. My lecturer used this two-period model in the lectures, but I know one can generalise this to an arbitrary number of periods).
I'm struggling to understand how to apply this to an informationally asymmetric credit market. Suppose we are dealing with an informationally asymmetric credit market where the lending rate is $r_L$ and the borrowing rate is $r_B$, with $r_L < r_B$. If the government cuts taxes in the current period using the lending rate, the right-hand side of the equation above becomes $N(t - \Delta t) + \frac{N(t + \Delta t(1 + r_L))}{...}$? Which interest rate should I put in the denominator of the second term, $r_L$ or $r_B$?
